# Determining whether a struct is of default value without "Equals"; aka ReferenceEquals for structs

Tags: c#, reflection

For some general helper methods I'm writing, I'd like to be able to invoke special processing when that value is the default value of its type.  For reference types, that's easy - the default value is `null`.  I can't use a generic type parameter, although I could work around that.

I can do something like this:

```
public bool DetectPossiblyUninitializedValue(object val) {
    return val== null ||
        val.GetType().IsValueType 
        && Equals(val, Activator.CreateInstance(val.GetType());
}
```

That's what I'm using right now, but it depends on the implementation of `Equals`.  That's fine, but not ideal.  In particular, some implementations might override Equals to support more usable semantics in normal scenarios.  It's actually not uncommon to treat the default value as special here because it's so unavoidable in .NET due to default initialization.

However, in this case, I just want to know whether the object may have been initialized, and I therefore don't want any custom equality or whatever.  Basically, I want to know whether the memory region the struct occupies is filled with zero's as the VM guarrantees after initialization, and no more.  In a sense I'm looking for something akin to `ReferenceEquals` for structs: a comparison disregarding the underlying object's own implementation.

How can I compare raw struct values without using `Equals`?  Can I compare raw struct values at all?

***Edit:*** I'm using this to hookup classes+structs representing domain-specific notions connected by essentially arbitrary code representing various business rules to a GUI.  Some old code essentially deals with possibly nested dictionaries of string to arbitrary objects, which thus requires a bunch of unchecked casts or `dynamic`; creating these is error prone.  So it's nice to be able to work with the typed objects relatively directly.  On the other hand, it's useful for the GUI and wrapping code to treat possibly uninitialized values differently; and although a case-by-case, type-by-type solution is possible, that's *lots* of code; a sensible default is useful.  Really what I want is a method of automatically generating a type that's identical to another but with all properties/public fields extended to include a value "uninitialized", but that's not a realistic feature to expect - by contrast in a dynamic world this would be trivially achievable, though without typesafety elsewhere...

***Answers:*** Mehrdad posted an answer on [how to directly access the bits of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427861/determining-whether-a-struct-is-of-default-value-without-equals-aka-referencee/6428236#6428236); I added [an implementation using that to detect possibly uninitialized values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427861/determining-whether-a-struct-is-of-default-value-without-equals-aka-referencee/6450250#6450250).

Comment: Can you use reflection? You can compare the values/references of members in struct.

Comment: I can definitely use reflection - but this just kindof delays the problem.  What do I do with the members? recurse... until what?

Comment: note that there are subtle exceptions like doubles, where -0.0 == 0.0 even though the bitpatterns differ.

Comment: ReferenceEquals for structs?  What about a method that just returns false?

Comment: Yeah exactly -- `aka ReferenceEquals for structs` makes no sense...

Comment: @Mehrdad, he means compairing the value of the two structs directly, without taking into account any override logic.  Similar to how ReferenceEquals compares only the value, not what the values point to.

Comment: @Buh: In that case, @Eamon might want to Google `FastEqualsCheck` and `CanCompareBits`.

Comment: @Ben Robinson & Mehdad: hence *akin* i.e. related to, similar, not identical.

Comment: @Eamon: I think we were looking at the title, not the text, when we pointed that out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're worried about the overhead of boxing (*and you've **measured** that this is a bottleneck*), you can solve it differently:

Create two temporary boxed instances of your struct as an `object`, which can be reused for all structs. Using `Reflection.Emit`, create a method that uses the [`Unbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox.aspx) opcode to *copy* a struct to a the boxed version. (This lets you avoid an allocation.) Do the same thing with the other boxed struct, then call `Equals` on the objects.

---

#### Note:

I don't know if the overhead of a delegate call is actually faster, but you could try anyway and see. If you find out it's not, then you could always do more than one comparison at once -- pass in an array or something. It gets complicated, but if you **know** this is the bottleneck then it might be worth it, depending on how big your `struct`s are.

---

#### Hackier Solution:

I'm not *supporting* this solution, merely suggesting that it exists. *If you don't know what this is doing, don't use it.*

```
bool UnsafeHackyEquals<T>(ref T a, ref T b) where T : struct
{
    TypedReference pA = __makeref(a), pB = __makeref(b);
    var size = SizeOf<T>();
    IntPtr* ppA = (IntPtr*)&pA, ppB = (IntPtr*)&pB;
    //Now ppA[0] is a pointer to a, and ppB[0] is a pointer to b.
    //You have the size of both, so you can do a bitwise comparison.
}
```

To find the size of a struct:

```
static class ArrayOfTwoElements<T> { static readonly T[] Value = new T[2]; }

static uint SizeOf<T>()
{
    unsafe 
    {
        TypedReference
            elem1 = __makeref(ArrayOfTwoElements<T>.Value[0] ),
            elem2 = __makeref(ArrayOfTwoElements<T>.Value[1] );
        unsafe
        { return (uint)((byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem2) - (byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem1)); }
    }
}
```

Yes, it'd kind of undocumented. But if you're worried about that, you could just *emit* this method instead (because the `MkRefAny` opcode is indeed documented), so that's not an issue. However, this example can break on other platforms, so be careful...

Comment: Speaking of pointers, don't you required to pin them in this case.

Comment: @DiVan: Ah yes indeed, that's another danger (unless you're sure they're on the stack). You can just pin the corresponding objects with `GCHandle`, or pin a different (known) unmanaged member of the object through `fixed`. The first one might be slow, so I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: @DiVan: Well actually, if your code is single-threaded, that's not an issue -- there's no allocation happening here, so the GC shouldn't kick in.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution!  This is indeed perhaps a little nasty, another approach may be warranted.

Comment: I've expanded your snippet into a complete solution in [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427861/determining-whether-a-struct-is-of-default-value-without-equals-aka-referencee/6450250#6450250).

Answer (score 2):

With the limited time I have to understand your requirements, I'm just going to throw something out here for you to ponder. though it does involve operator overloading (which, in turn, *is* implementation specific):

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int Bar;

    public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return a.Bar == b.Bar;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return !(a.Bar == b.Bar);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Then, to compare:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo { Bar = 1 };

if (foo1 == default(Foo))
{
    Console.WriteLine("foo1 is equal to default");
}

if (foo2 != default(Foo))
{
    Console.WriteLine("foo2 is not equal to default");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Original Poster here:  I've settled on ...*not*... using the solution below, extended from Mehrdad's notes.  It works, but I don't think the overall trickiness is worth it to catch a few more uninitialized values in the default implementation.

But if others ever care here it is:

```
public static bool PossiblyUninitialized(object a) {
    if(a == null) return true;
    Type t = a.GetType();
    return t.IsValueType &&
        helpers.GetOrAdd(t, _=>{
            var method = typeof(StructHelpers<>).MakeGenericType(t)
                .GetMethod("PossiblyUninitialized");
            var objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object),"obj");
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<object,bool>>(
                    Expression.Call(method,Expression.Convert(objParam,t)),
                    objParam
                ).Compile();
        })(a);
}
static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object,bool>> helpers = 
                    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object,bool>>();

unsafe static class StructHelpers<T> where T : struct { 
    public static readonly uint ByteCount = SizeOf();

    static uint SizeOf()
    {
        T[] arr = new T[2];
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(arr);
        TypedReference
            elem0 = __makeref(arr[0]),
            elem1 = __makeref(arr[1]);
        return (uint)((byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem1) - (byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem0)); 
        handle.Free();
    }

    public static bool PossiblyUninitialized(T a)
    {
        TypedReference pA = __makeref(a);
        var size = ByteCount;
        IntPtr* ppA = (IntPtr*)(&pA);
        int offset = 0;
        while(size - offset>=8) {
            if(*(long*)(*ppA+offset) != 0)
                return false;
            offset+=8;
        }
        while(size - offset>0) {
            if(*(byte*)(*ppA+offset) != 0)
                return false;
            offset++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

void Main()//LINQpad
{
    StructHelpers<decimal>.ByteCount.Dump();
    PossiblyUninitialized(0m).Dump();//true
    PossiblyUninitialized(0.0m).Dump();//false
    PossiblyUninitialized(0.0).Dump();//true
    PossiblyUninitialized(-0.0).Dump();//false
    PossiblyUninitialized("").Dump();//false
}
```

Comment: Added an answer reimplementing this with System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Eamon Nerbonne's answer can now be implemented using [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) without having to use undocumented/unsupported features and raw pointers:

```
// Essentially unchanged from Eamon Nerbonne's version
public static bool IsDefaultValue([CanBeNull] object a)
{
  if (a == null) return true;

  Type type = a.GetType();

  return type.IsValueType &&
         helpers.GetOrAdd(
           type,
           t =>
           {
             var method = typeof(StructHelpers<>).MakeGenericType(t)
              .GetMethod(nameof(StructHelpers<int>.IsDefaultValue));
             var objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "obj");
             return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(
                 Expression.Call(method, Expression.Convert(objParam, t)),
                 objParam)
              .Compile();
           })(a);
}

static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object,bool>> helpers = 
  new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object,bool>>();

static class StructHelpers<T> where T : struct
{
  // ReSharper disable StaticMemberInGenericType
  static readonly int ByteCount = Unsafe.SizeOf<T>();
  static readonly int LongCount = ByteCount / 8;
  static readonly int ByteRemainder = ByteCount % 8;
  // ReSharper restore StaticMemberInGenericType

  public static bool IsDefaultValue(T a)
  { 
    if (LongCount > 0)
    {
      ref long p = ref Unsafe.As<T, long>(ref a);

      // Inclusive end - don't know if it would be safe to have a ref pointing
      // beyond the value as long as we don't read it
      ref long end = ref Unsafe.Add(ref p, LongCount - 1);

      do
      {
        if (p != 0) return false;
        p = ref Unsafe.Add(ref p, 1);
      } while (!Unsafe.IsAddressGreaterThan(ref p, ref end));
    }

    if (ByteRemainder > 0)
    {
      ref byte p = ref Unsafe.Add(
                     ref Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref a),
                     ByteCount - ByteRemainder);

      ref byte end = ref Unsafe.Add(ref p, ByteRemainder - 1);

      do
      {
        if (p != 0) return false;
        p = ref Unsafe.Add(ref p, 1);
      } while (!Unsafe.IsAddressGreaterThan(ref p, ref end));
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General-purpose struct comparison needs to be done using something like Reflection -- basically, you need to compare each field in the structures separately. You could use unsafe/unmanaged code to, for example, copy the structure into a byte[] and scan for non-zero bytes, but relying on underlying VM guarantees like that may be a bad idea. (C#, the language, only guarantees that each field has its "default" value -- the fact that the default value is 0 is a CLR-specific detail that may change.)

There's several solutions for comparing structs, including a fairly compact LINQ solution, in the answers to [Compare two structs' values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983410/compare-two-structs-values-in-c).

You can use the `default` keyword to get a default structure to compare with, like:

```
    var blank = default(type)
```

Building on that LINQ solution, this ought to do what you want:

```
static bool IsDefault<T> ( T b ) where T : struct
{
    T a = default(T);
    var differences = from fielda in a.GetType().GetFields()
              join fieldb in b.GetType().GetFields() on fielda.Name equals fieldb.Name
              where !fielda.GetValue(a).Equals(fieldb.GetValue(b))
              select fielda.Name;
    return !differences.Any();
}
```

EDIT:

If your structs, in turn, have their own members that are structs, this will unfortunately fall back on `.Equals()` to compare those. If that's a problem, using a more long-winded `foreach` loop over the fields and handling the struct-type fields separately would also work, on the same principle.

Comment: The CLR's 0 behaviour is clearly specified, and so old and so reasonable, I'm quite OK with depending on that.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Value Types` you are considering are all "under your control" or will be tailor made to work with your code you can always make them implement a `readonly bool IsInitialized` field and check it through reflection.

If not, I find it hard to do what you want without using `Equals`. You could theoretically iterate through the fields using reflection to check if all fields are set to their default values.

Comment: The reason I'm not doing this is that the project is rather large with *lot's* of types reflecting domain-specific notions.  This means adding lots of boilerplate.  It's extremely valuable to have excellent defaults because it means fewer classes actually need to do anything custom at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can I compare raw struct values at all? - **No**. CLR itself uses reflection in order to compare two structures field-by-field.
Equals is your only hope. Value types should implement Equals, that is not differ from field-by-field reflection comparison. Otherwise, the Value Type is not a ValueType.

Consider the following

```
struct Bla
{
    int Data;
}
...
{
    Bla a = new Bla();
    Bla b = new Bla();
    a.Data = 10;
    a.Data = 0;

    Console.Writeline(IsDefault(a));
    Console.Writeline(IsDefault(b));
}
```

What would you expect to receive? We're talking structs here.

Comment: Would it need? ... donno. But it definitely does. That's why overriding Equals on structs is very good thing.

Comment: Check; good point. Equals is Object.Equals and hence needs 'reflection' or similar cow-powers. +1

Comment: It's defintely *possible*, but hacky. See my solution for how to do this. (All you need is a pointer to the structs, which is obtainable.)